# Set Time Interval in Timer in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin App, I want to set the timer interval for timer e.g. Start after 5 seconds and run for 10 seconds.

**Here is my code sample**

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
{
    FaceIdentityInstruction = "Look Down";
    return false;
});
```

Comment: then you need two timers, one to start the action and one to stop it.  Use System.Timers instead of Device.StartTimer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add [System.Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netcore-3.1) after `Device.StartTimer` 5 seconds.

```
private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
static int count = 0;
public PageListView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Console.WriteLine("Timer prepare for running");
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timer run");
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        return false;
    });
}


private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    if (count==10)
    {
        aTimer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Timer Stop");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
10-23 10:34:14.250 I/mono-stdout(29128): Timer prepare for running
10-23 10:34:19.262 I/mono-stdout(29128): Timer run
10-23 10:34:29.286 I/mono-stdout(29128): Timer Stop
```

Comment: @IngmarBergman Okey, I will check that. If good ideas will update there.